# How to get PowerShell to read line by line and pass it into another command?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

A lot of the questions around the internet for this specific topic are oriented into BASH for linux, I was wondering if the same thing can be achieved using just PowerShell.

On Bash, one can use:

```bsh
for line in $(cat file.txt); do echo $line; done
```

And then bash will loop through each line of file.txt and send it to echo or whatever command you're using.

How can the same thing be achieved on Windows's **powershell**?

I found that PS has the "`Get-Content`" command that works similarly to "`cat`", but I couldn't continue from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok it turns out that it was not that difficult but I'll leave it here for the future people of the internet.

PowerShell has a defined set of Loops, one of them called [`ForEach`](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/PowerShell/Loops#ForEach)
One can simply do:

```powershell
ForEach ($line in Get-Content [File]) {[Command]) $line}
```

Where `[File]` is the file path you're reading from and
Where `[Command]` is the command you're sending each line into.

Just as an example:

```powershell
ForEach ($line in Get-Content thingstoecho.txt) {echo $line}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to your answer, which reads the entire file before passing the first line for subsequent processing, is to leverage the pipeline and begin processing once the first line is read.

```
Get-Content thingstoecho.txt | ForEach-Object { echo $_ }
```

For smaller files, the difference can be trivial. But for large datasets, the pipeline appraoch is less likely to strain resources as it doesn't try to hold the entire file in memory at one time.

Comment: As per the long term PowerShell MVP and author of the regularly recommend reading, [PowerShell in a Month of Lunches](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=powershell+in+a+month+of+lunches+4th+edition&crid=VL0PYXT3A70C&sprefix=powershell+in+a+mon%2Caps%2C398&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_3_19), Don Jones, ... [Why Get-Content Ain’t Yer Friend | PowerShell.org](https://powershell.org/2013/10/why-get-content-aint-yer-friend)

Comment: Nice and clean. Love how the two tasks are separated -  reading the file and processing the call.